# Get the startup path in a vb.net console exe

Tags: vb.net, io

How do get the startup path ( system.windows.forms.application.StartupPath ) of my exe without adding a reference to system.windows.forms?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

which would work for most cases.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: @KiwiBastard's answer is the correct method:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

---

Add a reference to `System.Reflection` and use

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

EDIT: Depending where you intend getting the startup path, this might be more appropriate:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the startup path without reflection by using:

```
IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
```