# What is the correct way to reference files?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, game-engine

I'm messing about trying to make a game in VB.NET with a winforms application. I have data about spritesheets(frame info, animation time etc) in an XML document and I've been referencing that file as such;

```
Dim XMLDocument As New XmlDocument
XMLDocument.Load("C:\Development\Personal\GameConcept\GameConcepts\GameConcepts\SpriteSheet_FrameInfo.xml")
```

I'm then getting the appropriate information for the frames from various nodes.

However, I understand that when this application is published it will need to reference that XML file form wherever it is stored on the user's computer; what method should I use to reference the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you'd use the [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to "build" the path based on a starting location, such as [the folder where your application was started](https://stackoverflow.com/q/300578/65358).

This allows you to work from a relative path (the install folder) to the appropriate file, without hard coding it.

This would look something like (the "...." is assuming you leave things in "bin\Release" or similar):

```
XMLDocument.Load(Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "..\..\SpriteSheet_FrameInfo.xml"))
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the **SpriteSheet_FrameInfo.xml** file not be in the same directory as the compiled binary?

Comment: I would think that files of this nature would be stored in the C:\ProgramData\ folder for the app.